# TikZ: Is drawing an arc that either curves to much or isn't long enough

Tags: tikz-pgf, arc

```
\documentclass[convert = false, tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (O) at (0, 0);
  \coordinate (M) at (4, 0);

  \def\angle{130}

  \draw (O) -- (M);
  \draw (M) -- ++(\angle:2cm) coordinate (SOI);

  \begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
    \path[name path global = circ] (O) circle[radius = 1.5cm];
    \path[name path global = xline] (O) -- +(-10, 0);
    \path[name path global = yline] (O) -- +(0, 2);
    \path[name path global = toE] (SOI) -- ++(-170:8cm);
    \path[name intersections = {of = yline and toE, by = E}];
    \path[name intersections = {of = xline and toE, by = I}];
    \path[name intersections = {of = circ and toE, by = P1}];
  \end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}

  \draw (SOI) -- (E);

  \draw[-latex] let
    \p0 = (I),
    \p1 = (M),
    \p2 = (P1),
    \n1 = {atan2(\x1 - \x0, \y1 - \y0)},
    \n2 = {atan2(\x2 - \x0, \y2 - \y0)},
    \n3 = {1.5cm}
  in (I) +(\n1:\n3) arc[radius = \n3, start angle = \n1, end angle = \n2];

  \draw[-latex] let
    \p0 = (O),
    \p1 = (M),
    \p2 = (P1),
    \n1 = {atan2(\x1 - \x0, \y1 - \y0)},
    \n2 = {atan2(\x2 - \x0, \y2 - \y0)},
    \n3 = {1.5cm}
  in (O) +(\n1:\n3) arc[radius = \n3, start angle = \n1, end angle = \n2];

  \draw[-latex] let
    \p0 = (I),
    \p1 = (M),
    \p2 = (SOI),
    \n1 = {atan2(\x1 - \x0, \y1 - \y0)},
    \n2 = {atan2(\x2 - \x0, \y2 - \y0)},
    \n3 = {1.5cm}
  in (I) +(\n1:\n3) arc[radius = \n3, start angle = \n1, end angle = \n2];

  \draw[-latex] let
    \p0 = (O),
    \p1 = (M),
    \p2 = (SOI),
    \n1 = {atan2(\x1 - \x0, \y1 - \y0)},
    \n2 = {atan2(\x2 - \x0, \y2 - \y0)},
    \n3 = {1.5cm}
  in (O) +(\n1:\n3) arc[radius = \n3, start angle = \n1, end angle = \n2];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

1. Using `(P1)`

> If we consider the code above, the arc that is long enough curves too much and the arc that has the right amount of curve is too short.  How can I get the right amount of curve with the correct length in a case like this?

1. Using `(SOI)`

> Both curves are too short but neither appear to over arc.

What can I do here?

[image]

---

@Jake, your code that switches `y` and `x` rotates my vector to appear horizontal not vertical.

```
 \draw[-latex] let
    \p0 = (O),
    \p1 = (M),
    \p2 = (SOI),
    \n1 = {atan2(\y1 - \y0, \x1 - \x0)},
    \n2 = {atan2(\y2 - \y0, \x2 - \x0)},
    \n3 = {veclen(\x2 - \x0, \y2 - \y1)},
    \n4 = {(\n1 + \n2) / 2}
  in (O) +(\n1:\n3) arc[radius = \n3, start angle = \n1, end angle = \n2];
```

The code above you posted produces:

[image]

Going back to `x` and then `y` produces:

[image]

---

The problem was the `(I)` coordinate.  It never actually existed but `LaTeX` wasn't returning any errors.  The path `toE` never intersected the `xline`.  Therefore, so when I was drawing from the `(I)`, the circle path making up the intersection origin was above `y = 0`.  Thus, causing the `(I)` arcs to be short.  To correct this, set

```
\path[name path global = toE] (SOI) -- ++(-170:9cm);
```

which changes the radius of the ray to `9cm` from `8cm`.

Comment: @Jake I still get the picture.  I had a `\n4` that was unnecessary in MWE so I forgot to remove the `,`.

Comment: @Jake do you know why there was no error message issued even though there was no intersection?

Comment: Interesting: That's an unexpected consequence of how the `by` mechanism for naming intersections is implemented. It turns out that all intersections are initially called `intersection-1`, and if you specify a custom name using `by`, that intersection is renamed to the chosen name. Now, once you've successfully found an intersection in a path, if later paths don't find their own intersection they'll just rename that initial intersection (which is what happened in your case). I'll file a bug report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was the `(I)` coordinate.  It never actually existed but `LaTeX` wasn't returning any errors.  The path `toE` never intersected the `xline`.  Therefore, so when I was drawing from the `(I)`, the circle path making up the intersection origin was above `y = 0`.  Thus, causing the `(I)` arcs to be short.  To correct this, set

```
\path[name path global = toE] (SOI) -- ++(-170:9cm);
```

which changes the radius of the ray to `9cm` from `8cm`.

At the current settings, an intersection never existed.

[image]

Unfortunately, `LaTeX` never spit out an error and let the line

```
\path[name intersections = {of = xline and toE, by = I}];
```

create the point `(I)` at the end of `toE`.  Since I constructed paths, I couldn't actually see this until I decided to look more closely, and without an error message saying there is no intersection or something along those lines, I was lead to believe everything worked.

With the new change, we obtain

[image]

by setting

```
\path[name path global = circ] (I) circle[radius = 7cm];
```

and using Jake's deleted method of `veclen` and putting it in the `pgfinterruptboundingbox` or else you will have unnecessary white space.

```
  \draw[-latex] let
    \p0 = (I),
    \p1 = (M),
    \p2 = (P1),
    \n1 = {atan2(\x1 - \x0, \y1 - \y0)},
    \n2 = {atan2(\x2 - \x0, \y2 - \y0)},
    \n3 = {veclen(\x2 - \x0, \y2 - \y1)},
    \n4 = {(\n1 + \n2) / 2}
  in (I) +(\n1:\n3) arc[radius = \n3, start angle = \n1, end angle = \n2]
  node[font = \tiny, fill = white, inner sep = 0] at ([shift = (I)] \n4:\n3)
  {\(\phi_1\)};
```